# ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'jupyter_bokeh. Panel interactive widget not displaying despite creating new python environment to solve issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook, widget, bokeh, panel, dashboard

I am making a simple panel interactive widgets display in a jupyter notebook. In this case I make a basic function that accepts a list of years and interactive widget will make a basic dropdown selector the user can choose a year. But my program crashes when I run the panel interact() to call on the function. It won't display a dropwdown selector object.

Imports

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import panel as pn
from panel.interact import interact
from panel import widgets
pn.extension()
import hvplot.pandas
```

Basic Function that accepts a list of years

```
list_of_years = ['2022', '2021', '2020', '2019', '2018', '2017']

def choose_year(year):
    '''Display the year that is chosen from a dropdown and echo/return it back. '''
    return(year)
```

Call on the interact() pass the choose_year function and the year parameter, in this case a list of years, and the interact function should output a dropdown list the user can interact with.

```
interact(choose_year, year=list_of_years)
```

I get an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\jakel\anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
    968 
    969             if method is not None:
--> 970                 return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    971             return None
    972         else:

c:\Users\jakel\anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\panel\viewable.py in _repr_mimebundle_(self, include, exclude)
    569 
    570         if config.comms in ('vscode', 'ipywidgets'):
--> 571             widget = ipywidget(self)
    572             if hasattr(widget, '_repr_mimebundle_'):
    573                 return widget._repr_mimebundle_(include, exclude)

c:\Users\jakel\anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\panel\io\notebook.py in ipywidget(obj, **kwargs)
    368     Returns an ipywidget model which renders the Panel object.
    369     """
--> 370     from jupyter_bokeh.widgets   import BokehModel
    371     from ..pane import panel
    372     model = panel(obj, **kwargs).get_root()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_bokeh'
```

I created a fresh new python environment and I am still getting the same problem.

Here are the steps and installs I did with my python environment

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab>=3
pip install python-dotenv
conda install -c anaconda nb_conda -y
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs -y
conda install update nodejs
conda install -c pyviz holoviz -y
conda install -c plotly plotly -y
```

Here are the package versions of everything in the environment

```
jupyterlab                3.3.2              
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      
jupyterlab_server         2.10.3             
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              
nodejs                    18.10.0
holoviz                   0.13.0
hvplot                    0.7.3
panel                     0.13.0
plotly                    5.6.0
bokeh                     2.4.2
```

This error is saying `ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'jupyter_bokeh'` but bokeh is clearly in the environment. It's usually auto-installed with other feature installs.

I have done numerous updates. I am using the right environments. I am creating new environments and not getting any progress. Why does it keep saying this error?

Comment: `bokeh` and `jupyter_bokeh` are two separate packages. You need to install both.

Comment: But bokeh is in the environment. Please see the bottom of the post. I have bokeh 2.4.2

Comment: I'm not sure why you think having one installed means the other must be installed. It doesn't. They are two separate packages, you need to install both. `jupyter_bokeh` is not part of, or included with, the main Bokeh package.